# Getting google dev_acc id programmatically

Tags: google-play, google-cloud-storage, google-play-developer-api, google-api-ruby-client

Given that a user (Google Play's account owner) already authenticated my application (Google App Engine's service account) with the correct scopes...

Is there an endpoint in google API that returns the `dev_acc` parameter used to access their play store developer account?

to be specific I want to retrieve it to access the following URI
`https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=DEV_ACC_ID` or cloud storage buckets found in `gs://pubsite_prod_rev_DEV_ACC_ID/`
programmatically?

or alternatively, list all the cloud storage buckets they have? (including the `gs://pubsite_prod_rev_DEV_ACC_ID/` bucket)

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: No, it's not possible using the current APIs (and won't be implemented anytime soon)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I'll post here if I find a way.